# How to avoid deleting other packages while installing one package

Tags: angular, npm, primeng

Good day! I just newly update my angular2 project and I'm installing primeng. This is only happening when I'm installing the primeng. I just followed the given instruction [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/primeng).And this also happening when I'm installing other dependecy. How can I avoid this situation? And why this happening?

**This is my *package.json***

```
{
  "name": "Logic8-hris",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4200",
    "custom": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@99xt/ngx-pagination": "^0.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0",
    "@types/bootstrap-datepicker": "0.0.11",
    "@types/bootstrap-slider": "^9.9.0",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.46",
    "@types/fastclick": "^1.0.28",
    "@types/flot": "0.0.31",
    "@types/icheck": "^0.8.29",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "@types/jquery-knob": "^1.2.31",
    "@types/jquery.slimscroll": "^1.3.31",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.1",
    "@types/morris.js": "^0.5.6",
    "admin-lte": "~2.4.2",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.23.5",
    "angular-datatables": "^5.0.0",
    "angular-draggable-droppable": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-popper": "^1.0.0-beta-1",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.5",
    "angular2-fullcalendar": "^1.1.1",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.8.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.7.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.5.1",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.16",
    "fastclick": "^1.0.6",
    "flot": "^0.8.0-alpha",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.8.2",
    "icheck": "^1.0.2",
    "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-knob": "^1.2.11",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "jszip": "^3.1.5",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "morris.js": "^0.5.0",
    "ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "ng2-bootstrap-modal": "^1.0.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^2.0.12",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.7.7",
    "ng2-pagination": "^2.0.2",
    "ng2-select2": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "ng2-slider-component": "^1.0.9",
    "ng2-uploader": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-uploader": "^4.2.2",
    "nouislider": "^11.0.3",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.35",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "primeng": "^5.2.0",
    "raphael": "^2.2.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "select2-bootstrap-theme": "0.1.0-beta.10",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.0.4",
    "socketio": "^1.0.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.4",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.37",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/node": "^9.4.5",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
    "codelyzer": "~4.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "jqueryui": "^1.11.1",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "tether": "^1.4.3",
    "ts-node": "4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.1",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be specific? Which packages are getting updated on installing `primeng`?

Comment: @KarthickManoharan i am instaling npm install primeng --save. and this is not also in primeng but it also in happened in popper.js

Comment: @KarthickManoharan when im installing primeng other modules are also deleted in node_modules

Comment: Verify that you are in the correct folder when you do `npm install primeng --save`

Comment: @KarthickManoharan i did. I dunno why this also happening when I'm installing popper.js